# c# animate the Alignment - possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, alignment

is it possible to create a c# animation for the AttachedPropertys like Alignment? Maybe 1 Second Move between the Change from HorizontalAlignment.Left to HorizontalAlignment.Right - is it possible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can't animate it in the sense of producing a smooth animation where something slides from left to right since they are discrete states.  There aren't any in-between values.  It is possible to create an "animation" which changes the alignment at some point from left to right, it just won't slide across.  You could also do a lot of work and measure all the controls to manually create an animation which moves something from one side of the screen to the other using things like Canvas.Left or margins to position the controls.

The attached property part is not an issue, just use the full name of the attached property in the target property part of your animation.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not possible to directly animate smoothly between two properties like

```
HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
```

to

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
```

I did come up with a way to do this for an app in a way that I thought might be worth sharing. I simply placed the control in a grid that took up the full pane of the window. I aligned the control to the bottom right of the grid. Then I animated the grid with to transform and scale the corner down that I need to the point I want to align the control too (center in this example. See the complete code below.

```
<Grid Margin="5,5,14,70" Visibility="{Binding Path=AdminModeIsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource CollapsedVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CenterPanel}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="2" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To=".5" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="2" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To=".5" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
    <Image Height="15" Source="\Images\Test.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, here is an example:

```
class StoryBoardManager : System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard
{
    public void ChangeRectangleAlignment(DependencyObject target, VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment, HorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment, int BeginTimeMillisecond)
    {
        ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames objectAnimation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames()
        {
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0)
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(objectAnimation, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(objectAnimation, new PropertyPath("(FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment)"));
        DiscreteObjectKeyFrame keyFrame = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(horizontalAlignment, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(BeginTimeMillisecond));
        objectAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrame);
        this.Children.Add(objectAnimation);
    }
}
```

For more information, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473458/how-can-you-use-objectanimationusingkeyframes-from-pure-c).